# parameterized test with cartesian product of arguments in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

Just wondering, is there any (more) elegant way of parameterizing with the cartesian product? This is what I figured out so far:

```
numbers    = [1,2,3,4,5]
vowels     = ['a','e','i','o','u']
consonants = ['x','y','z']

cartesian = [elem for elem in itertools.product(*[numbers,vowels,consonants])]

@pytest.fixture(params=cartesian)
def someparams(request):
  return request.param

def test_something(someparams):
  pass
```

At least I'd like to encapsulate numbers, vowels, consonants and cartesian in the fixture function.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I can think of two ways to do this. One uses parametrized fixtures, and one parametrizes the test function. It's up to you which one you find more elegant.

Here is the test function parametrized:

```
import itertools
import pytest

numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
consonants = ['x','y','z']


@pytest.mark.parametrize('number,vowel,consonant',
    itertools.product(numbers, vowels, consonants)
)
def test(number, vowel, consonant):
    pass
```

Of note, the second argument to the parametrize decorator can be an iterable, not just a list.

Here is how you do it by parametrizing each fixture:

```
import pytest

numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
consonants = ['x','y','z']


@pytest.fixture(params=numbers)
def number(request):
    return request.param

@pytest.fixture(params=vowels)
def vowel(request):
    return request.param

@pytest.fixture(params=consonants)
def consonant(request):
    return request.param


def test(number, vowel, consonant):
    pass
```

Your intuition was correct. By parametrizing each of multiple fixtures, pytest takes care of creating all the permutations that arise.

The test output is identical. Here is a sample (I ran py.test with the -vv option):

```
test_bar.py:22: test[1-a-x] PASSED
test_bar.py:22: test[1-a-y] PASSED
test_bar.py:22: test[1-a-z] PASSED
test_bar.py:22: test[1-e-x] PASSED
test_bar.py:22: test[1-e-y] PASSED
test_bar.py:22: test[1-e-z] PASSED
test_bar.py:22: test[1-i-x] PASSED
```

Answer (score 139):

You can apply multiple `parametrize` arguments, in which case they will generate a product of all parameters:

```
import pytest

numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
consonants = ['x','y','z']


@pytest.mark.parametrize('number', numbers)
@pytest.mark.parametrize('vowel', vowels)
@pytest.mark.parametrize('consonant', consonants)
def test(number, vowel, consonant):
    pass
```

Comment: This should work in Python 2 just fine. What error are you getting?

pytest 5.X no longer supports Python 2.7 and Python 3.4, but users of those Python versions executing "pip install pytest" will get the last compatible version, 4.6.X.

Answer (score 8):

I think besides an elegant solution, you should also consider both the amount of time each option will take and the amount of code you'll have to maintain.

### Possible solutions

1. Using `parametrize` once with itertools (provided by Frank T)
2. Using 3 fixtures (provided by Frank T)
3. Using `parametrize` 3 times (provided by Bruno Oliveira)
4. Using 1 fixture and itertools (provided in the question)

### Solution 1

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('number, vowel, consonant',
                         itertools.product(numbers, vowels, consonants))
def test(number, vowel, consonant):
    pass
```

### Solution 2

```
@pytest.fixture(params=numbers)
def number(request): return request.param

@pytest.fixture(params=vowels)
def vowel(request): return request.param

@pytest.fixture(params=consonants)
def consonant(request): return request.param


def test(number, vowel, consonant):
    pass
```

### Solution 3

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('number', numbers)
@pytest.mark.parametrize('vowel', vowels)
@pytest.mark.parametrize('consonant', consonants)
def test(number, vowel, consonant):
    pass
```

### Solution 4

```
@pytest.fixture(params=cartesian)
def someparams(request):
  return request.param

def test_something(someparams):
  pass
```

When it comes to elegance, I consider that **Solution 3** is the best option because it has less code maintain, and it does not require to import `itertools`. After that **Solution 1** is the best choice because you don't need to write fixtures as **Solution 4**, and **Solution 2**. **Solution 4** is probably better than **Solution 2** because it requires less code to maintain.

When it comes to performance I run each solution using `numbers = list(range(100))`, and I got the following results:

```
|  Solution  |  Time    | 
| Solution 1 |  3.91s   |
| Solution 2 |  3.59s   |
| Solution 3 |  3.54s   |
| Solution 4 |  3.09s   |
```