# Pytest skip test with certain parameter value

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have tests that I want to parameterize, but there are certain tests that should only be applied to one value of the parameters. To give a specific example, below, I would like to apply parameters `one` and `two` to `test_A`, but only supply parameter `one` to `test_B`.

**Current Code**

```
@pytest.fixture(params=['one', 'two'])
def data(request):

    if request.param == 'one'
         data = 5
    return data

def test_A(data):

    assert True

def test_B(data):

    assert True
```

**Desired Results**

I basically want something that looks like this, but I can't figure out how to code this properly in pytest:

```
@pytest.fixture(params=['one', 'two'])
def data(request):

    data = 5
    return data

def test_A(data):

    assert True

@pytest.skipif(param=='two')
def test_B(data):

    assert True
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Building on your answer, you can check the input and call `pytest.skip()` if you don't want the test to run.

You can do the check in the test:

```
def test_A(data):
    assert True

def test_B(data):
    if data.param == 'two':
        pytest.skip()
    assert 'foo' == 'foo'
```

Or you could redefine the test fixture in a subclass:

```
class TestA:
    def test_A(self, data):
        assert True

class TestB:
    @pytest.fixture
    def data(self, data):
        if data.param == 'two':
            pytest.skip()
        return data

    def test_B(self, data):
        assert 'foo' == 'foo'
```

One other minor suggestion: your `Data` class can be replaced with a namedtuple, i.e.

```
import collections
Data = collections.namedtuple('Data', 'data, param')
```

Comment: If I split my tests into two separate classes, would the parameterization still apply to TestA?

Comment: Yup, your `data` fixture is a parametrized test fixture, and it will remain parametrized. When you use a parametrized test fixture in another fixture, the parametrization "carries over". Using multiple parametrized fixtures generates all the resulting permutations. This answer gives some more complex examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22390931/1812727

Answer (score 1):

I found a working solution, but I also welcome more solutions as this feels a tad "hacky":

```
class Data:

    def__init__(self, data, param):
        self.data = data
        self.param = param

@pytest.fixture(params=['one', 'two'])
def data(request):

    data = 5
    return Data(data, request.param)

def test_A(data):

    assert True

def test_B(data):

    if data.param == 'two':
        assert True
    else:
        assert 'foo' == 'foo'
```