# How can I use test-data/external variable in 'pytest.dependency'?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, fixtures

Below pytest code works fine, which increments `value`.

```
import pytest
pytest.value = 1

def test_1():
    pytest.value +=1
    print(pytest.value)

def test_2():
    pytest.value +=1
    print(pytest.value)

def test_3():
    pytest.value +=1
    print(pytest.value)
```

**Output:**

```
Prints
2
3
4
```

I don't want to execute `test_2`, when `value=2`

Is it possible by `pytest.dependency()` ? If yes, how can i use variable `value` in `pytest.dependency` ?

If not `pytest.dependency`, Any alternative ?

or any better way of handling such scenarios ?

```
    import pytest
    pytest.value = 1
    
    def test_1():
        pytest.value +=1
        print(pytest.value)
    
    @pytest.dependency(value=2)  # or @pytest.dependency(pytest.value=2)
    def test_2():
        pytest.value +=1
        print(pytest.value)
    
    def test_3():
        pytest.value +=1
        print(pytest.value)
```

Can you please guide me ? Can this be done ?
Is this possible ?

Comment: Is this achievable ? Can anyone guide here ?

Comment: I haven't used `pytest.dependency`, but from what I see in the documentation, there is no such option - at least I couln't find it. What is it that you actually want to achieve?

Comment: @MrBean:  Thanks for responding. Scenario is to skip rest all test cases whenever value of 'value' =2. This 'value' keeps changing dynamically, based on test actions.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen : Could think of anything ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pytest skip test with certain parameter value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45676648/pytest-skip-test-with-certain-parameter-value)

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Thanks for that, had gone through that already. Actually, if there are many testcases, adding conditions like this in every test-case not a good idea. So, i thought to handle such stuffs outside test-case, i.e., pytest.dependency or pytest.skip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the value outside of the test (as it is the case in your example), you can skip the tests in a fixture based on the value:

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def skip_unwanted_values():
    if pytest.value == 2:
        pytest.skip(f"Value {pytest.value} shall not be tested")
```

In the example given above, where `pytest.value` is set to 2 after `test_1`, `test_2` and `test_3` would be skipped. Here is the output I get:

```
...
test_skip_tests.py::test_1 PASSED                                        [ 33%]2

test_skip_tests.py::test_2 SKIPPED                                       [ 66%]
Skipped: Value 2 shall not be tested

test_skip_tests.py::test_3 SKIPPED                                       [100%]
Skipped: Value 2 shall not be tested
failed: 0


======================== 1 passed, 2 skipped in 0.06s =========================
```

Comment: 'value' is not static. it's dynamic. If you look at snippet posted above, Initially, when ''value" is 1 , it executes test-cases and alters the 'value' based on some condition. When the 'value' changes to 2, should skip rest all the test cases.